# Can I use output variables to get a value?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure where I'm checking if username exists and if it does not exists insert into user table then gets userid for the same username. I was trying to use an output variable to get the userid. Am I going about this wrong?

```
alter Procedure Check_User_Name
(
    @username varchar(25),
    @password varchar(100),
    @role_id integer,
    @idn nvarchar output
)
As
Begin
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT idn=@idn
        FROM [user] WHERE username = @username)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [user] (username,[password],role_id) VALUES
        (@username, @password,@role_id)
        --select @idn=idn from [user]
        Print 'UserName inserted successfully'
    End
    Else IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [user] WHERE username = @username)
    Begin
        Print 'UserName already exists'
    End
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had it close -- After replacing your column names to match with what is in my user table, this worked for me.  (I think I replaced everything back).

On your `Else`, you're basically doing a second lookup by username - which is unnecessary in this case.

```
ALTER Procedure Check_User_Name
  (
@username varchar(25),
@password varchar(100),
 @role_id integer,
 @idn nvarchar(20) output
 )
 As
Begin
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT idn
         FROM [user] WHERE username = @username)
            BEGIN 
                INSERT INTO [user] (username,[password], role_id) VALUES 
                 (@username, @password) 
                select @idn=idn from [user] WHERE username = @username
                Print 'UserName inserted successfully'
            End
            Else
               Begin
                    Print 'UserName already exists'
                    SELECT @idn = idn FROM [user] 
                    WHERE username = @username
               End 

 END
 GO
```

Execute with:

```
 DECLARE @idnOut nVarChar(20)
 exec Check_User_Name @username = 'user2127184', @password = 'asdf', @role_id = 0,  @idn = @idnOut OUTPUT
 SELECT @idnOut
```

Comment: I specified a size on the @idn variable that you'll need to confirm.  Omitting the size defaults to 30 [SO Ref](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131499/what-is-the-effect-of-omitting-size-in-nvarchar-declaration)

Comment: it worked. while I'm here as u can see in my code that its not really using error handling just printing statements. could I use like a try, catch or @@error for that?

Comment: It depends on what the rest of your code is doing.  I'm not sure I would worry about it - since you're just doing an insert.  If the insert/select fails, I (personally) would just deal with it in my application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use out params, but I always avoid out params in SQL like I do in C# for the same reasons.

If you have a result set with just the UserId:

```
select @UserId;
```

then you expand it to include other things later:

```
select @UserId, @UserGuid;
```

without much trouble.

Even if you need to return a status (Login Allowed / Locked Out) and details you can just use multiple result sets:

```
select @Status;
select @UserId; //etc.
```

If you have out parameters you have to change the Signature of the procedure - which can be a problem if you are supporting multiple clients calling it.

The only change you need to make to the calling code with result sets is to keep finding the new column from the result set.