# Select does not work with variable in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server

I have a table called UserList which has UserName and UserPassword columns. When I query as below, it Works and returns the right data.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.UserList WHERE UserName = 'aliserin'
```

But when I try it as below, it doesn't give me any result. It just returns empty. It doesn't give an error, but I really didn't understand the reason. It is a local database if it matters.

```
declare
@UserName as NVARCHAR

SET
@UserName = 'aliserin'
SELECT * FROM dbo.UserList WHERE UserName = @UserName
```

When I try the same code on UserId constraint as below, it works. Does anyone has any idea why?

```
DECLARE @UserName1 AS NVARCHAR

SET @UserName1 = 2

SELECT * FROM dbo.UserList WHERE UserId = @UserName1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify a length parameter for the `varchar` type: [What is the effect of omitting size in nvarchar declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131499/what-is-the-effect-of-omitting-size-in-nvarchar-declaration)

> When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, **the default length is 1**. When n is not specified with the CAST function, the default length is 30.

This means your query is actually doing `SELECT * FROM UserList WHERE UserName = 'a'`.

So you want:

```
DECLARE @userName AS nvarchar(8)
SET @userName = 'aliserin'
SELECT * FROM dbo.UserList WHERE UserName = @userName
```

You can also simplify this by using the `DECLARE =` syntax and omitting the `AS` keyword (I avoid using `AS` for types as it's usually used to alias column names)

```
DECLARE @userName nvarchar(8) = 'aliserin'
SELECT * FROM dbo.UserList WHERE UserName = @userName
```